# Is it possible to compile a flutter package to import only the resulting binary in the project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I'm new to flutter, I've been creating a few packages in flutter that would be imported in several other (flutter) project. This packages are independently versioned.

My question is 'Is it possible to "compile" a flutter package (only dart code and some dependencies of flutter plugins) in order to obtain a binary file that I can add to my flutter project?'

I know I can add it as a dependency by **path** or by **git**, but my goal would be having several of this possible binary files in a dependency repository of my own...

So, is it possible?

Comment: Hi @guilherme, Please let me know if you found a way to do this ?